# Survey or questionnaire document class or package?

Tags: packages, templates, document-classes, questionnaire, statistics

I like to create surveys and questionnaires, what would be a good `\documentclass` or `package` to use?

Comment: If you're interested in writing your own class I wrote an article called [Writing a LaTeX Class File to Produce a Form](http://latex-community.org/know-how/latex/54-latex-document-classes/342-writing-a-latex-class-file-to-produce-a-form) on the [LaTeX Community site](http://latex-community.org/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [AcroTeX](http://www.acrotex.net/) bundle provides the [eqExamn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqexam) package.

D.P. Story (the AcroTeX author) has published a PracTeX article on the subject of creating surveys using TeX [Producing a TeX/LaTeX Online Survey with the eqExam Package](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/story-survey/story-survey.pdf)

Answer (score 11):

The Leibniz Institute for Social Sciences at the University of Duisburg, Essen, Germany developed the Questionnaire Development Documentation System (QDDS). Version III of this software includes two LaTeX styles that were created to implement paper based questionnaires:

- [paperandpencil.sty](http://www.qdds.org/fileadmin/files/Documentation_en_paper+pencil.pdf) for paper and pencil questionnaires, and
- [papy.sty](http://www.qdds.org/fileadmin/files/Documentation_en_papi.pdf) for paper assisted personal interviews.

The styles and some examples can be downloaded [here](http://www.qdds.de/index46f5.html?id=129).
[image]

Comment: looks like a nice package, but is not even on ctan.  they probably are not particularly eager to spread the word (package).

Comment: This looks nice, except for one aspect: it creates survey that fill many pages and this creates friction (and lower turnout) in my experience. I have therefore tried to create my own surveys in a more compact format.

Comment: @ChristianLindig, I am interested in your own surveys in a more compact format - can you tell me more?

Comment: See my GitHub Gist [survey.tex](https://gist.github.com/lindig/3935127350488c42b8cd40b317e4cbec). At the top is a logo that I have edited out to make it compile without it.

Comment: The "here" link is dead.

Comment: @wilx A copy of `paperandpencil.sty` can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/lukaskubanek/bachelor-thesis/blob/master/user-study-questionnaire/paperandpencil.sty), as referenced by [John Canning](https://johncanning.net/wp/?p=2126).

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend having a look at SDAPS, since it provides a class to build questionnaires. But the greates feature of this software is the ability to do optical mark recognition on the questionnaire built with this class. All you have to do is scan them. Have a look at the project website http://sdaps.org/

[image: SDAPS workflow]

[image: SDAPS LaTeX class example]

Comment: I agree, SDAPS in its whole, as a OS-independent software suite, looks really awesome with what I came up with. I cannot wait to try out the scanning feature. Thank you!

Comment: The scanning feature works great. I should also mention that if you run into some problems, be sure to contact the developer. He is really responsive and helpful.

Comment: Obrigado! FYI, I already contributed the Dutch TeX translation to the project.

Answer (score 6):

I found all the above solutions inconvenient to implement (e.g. `paperandpencil.sty` can't be used with document class, `eqExam` also has some inconvenient dependencies).

I really like [this solution by Sven Hartenstein](http://www.svenhartenstein.de/creating-questionnaires-with-latex/) -- no package necessary, and all questions are neatly formatted (only disadvantage: you need to add a number of extra definitions in the preamble). It's possible to use with all document classes. The above link also contains an example pdf.

You can also find the code on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/SocDataScience/latex-surveys).