# Can't install webomints package

Tags: packages, templates, document-classes

I'm trying to replicate the answer by Gonzalo Medina here: [document class for a restaurant menu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38091/document-class-for-a-restaurant-menu)

However, I am unable to get the decorative corners. My results:
[image]

In attempting to remedy this, I figured I needed to install the `webomints` package. Since it is not listed on Tex Live Utility, I figured I had to download the .zip and install it manually. To do this, I put the `webomints` folder into `~Library/texmf/tex/latex.` I tried to re-compile, but now it fails with the error message:

`! Font U/webo/xl/n/80=WebOMintsGD at 95.99976pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file
 not found.`

I looked up what this error message means and found that it suggests I am missing the `WebOMintsGD.tfm` file. I tried looking up how to fix this and found various problems that did not apply.

Any advice is appreciated as I've already spent a couple hours trying to solve this silly problem.

Possibly relevant error messages:
`LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape`T1/cmr/m/sc' in size <24> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 86.`

Comment: It sounds like you need to follow the installation instructions more carefully:  http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/fonts/webomints/README

Comment: @Thruston Thanks for sharing that. I followed directions 1,2,3 but I still get the error message: 
`LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 50.`
Not sure if it's relevant, but none of the folders within texmf existed until I made them to install `webomints.` I believe I am using pdflatex based on the message from RStudio "Running pdflatex on christmasDayDinnerMenu.tex...failed". However, I still tried steps 4 and 5 anyway, but neither worked. The samples compile successfully though. I am using a Mac.

Comment: @Thruston Do ***not*** use `getnonfreefonts` ever. Use `getnonfreefonts-sys`. The only exception is if you do not have admin rights and then it is worth asking very seriously whether you really need the font *that* badly and whether you are prepared to put up with the extra hassle (and remember to go through the extra hassle) involved.

Comment: If you have run `getnonfreefonts` you now have a problem (or will have). You should undo its doings to prevent this and use `getnonfreefonts-sys` instead if you still want the font.

Comment: See [Why shouldn't I use getnonfreefonts to install additional fonts? Why shouldn't I use updmap when installing or removing fonts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i/255711#255711). [I wrote the question and answer there in response to a request to provide a standard reference for this issue.]

Comment: @cfr thanks, I wasn't aware of the issues (or at least I hadn't noticed the difference).  I'll remove the link in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Thruston Thanks. It is very easy not to realise because right after using the wrong commands, everything works just perfectly. It is only *later* that you get mysterious problems and those problems likely have nothing to do with the additional fonts you installed, but some other font or fonts altogether. So the potential for confusion is very high :(.

Comment: @user2205916 That warning is perfectly normal and nothing to worry about. (The one about `cmr`.] By the way, would you consider changing your user name to something a little less generic? There are a lot of `userXXXXXXX`s on this site ;).

Answer (score 3):

For the less tech-savvy/deadline-driven looking for a quick solution, here are concise instructions on how to solve the above problem.

1. Download the installer [install-getnonfreefonts](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts) from https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/ to an arbitrary directory.
2. Open Terminal and type: `cd <directory containing the downloaded file here minus brackets>`
3. In Terminal, type: `texlua install-getnonfreefonts`
4. In Terminal, type: `getnonfreefonts-sys -all`. This installs the fonts system−wide, which is the best practices solution. For more on why, see @cfr's link in the comments above.

Comment: It would be rather more courteous to ask Thruston  to post an answer rather than creating one from that suggestion.