# Why is my font shape undefined?

Tags: fonts, texlive

I am trying to use the second answer provided in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38091/document-class-for-a-restaurant-menu), which involves installing a new font. I use TeX Live (2017 release) under MacOS. I have installed the font and left the LaTeX code untouched so far, exactly as in the answer linked above. Note that the code is intended to be ran using XeLaTeX. However I get the following error message:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/zorna/m/n' undefined
(Font) using `U/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 6.
```

However, when I run `tex testfont` in the terminal and then asks for the table, it outputs a DVI with the correct symbols, confirming that the installation of the font has been successful. Any idea what could have gone wrong?

The following MWE gives the same error message:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{zorna}

\begin{document}
\zorna{a}
\end{document}
```

with the additional `zorna.sty` file placed in the same folder:

```
%Filename: zorna.sty 
%Created by: TTF2TEX.perl, Sam  5 jui 2010 22:40:14 CEST

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}%}
\ProvidesPackage{zorna}%
%
\newcommand*{\zorna}[1]{{%
\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{zorna}\selectfont #1}}
\endinput
```

Comment: Still nobody? I updated TexLive, Texmaker as well as my MacOS distribution and the problem persists. I believe that I am doing something wrong with the installation of the font. But I can't figure out what since tex testfont says its installed!

Comment: Why not just put the actual TrueType font in `/Library/Fonts` and then use `fontspec` to load it, if you're using XeLaTeX anyway. This would be much simpler.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for your answer! I tried that, without success. I put the font called "Orna4.ttf" in my Library/Fonts folder and tried to call it with \setmainfont{Orna4} and \setmainfont{Orna4.ttf}, both return the same error as in the OP unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following document compiles without error for me, having installed the Orna 4 font into `/Library/Fonts` and compiled with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\orna{Orna 4}
\begin{document}
\Huge
{\orna a b c d e f }
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]