# How to reproduce tkz-euclide documentation

Tags: documentation, tkz-euclide

I'm trying to reproduce the tkz-euclide documentation with the files
available in CTAN (and TeXLive), but I haven't succeeded, it's missing `couverture.tex` ,
`zorna.sty` and I get the error:

```
!  Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `sectioncolor'
```

along with others.

I sent an email to the author (@Alain Matthes), but I don't know if he got it or just didn't get an answer.

**TMP EDIT**

```
ls $(kpsewhich tkz-doc.cls)
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-doc/tkz-doc.cls
```

```
[pablo@worktex ~] $ ls /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-doc/
tkz-doc.cls  tkzexample.sty
[pablo@worktex ~] $ ls /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-doc/
couverture.tex  README  tkz-doc.cfg
```

Comment: @AlainMatthes You still participate in this community?

Comment: You can only @-ping people who have commented (or edited the question I think), so Alain won't have been notified of your comment. That said, he was active three hours ago according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/alain-matthes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the use of @-ping...I hope you go back online and check the `tag`

Comment: If you have any problems I can help you and detail some points. I'm sorry about the chat, but I've never used

Comment: You will consider adopting in the future (https://github.com/tkz-sty)

Comment: Thanks for your question because it's a real problem. I have a lot of problem actually with my packages. I'm not sure I'm going to be able to keep this up if I can't manage. I don't know anything about `git` I'm interested, but it was `David Carlisle` who took care of it when I was sick. He would have to explain to me how I can handle these pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilation of the documentation is not obvious and I'm in the process of adding tests for the fonts and the engines.

You need to compile with lualatex or xelatex. It's possible with pdflatex but in this case you need to change some packages for the fonts.

There is an answer [about the font orna 4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38091/document-class-for-a-restaurant-menu/38164#38164) but you can change the documentation like this to avoid the problem.

Il the file `TKZdoc-euclide-main.tex` line 97 you have `\usepackage{fourier-otf,zorna}`. Remove `zorna`  `\usepackage{fourier-otf}`

Then you comment the block below line 128 to 147

```
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
\setlength\unitlength{1mm}
\put(70,120){%
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (30pt,30pt){\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \zorna{c}};  
 \node at (270pt,30pt){\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \zorna{d}};
 \node at (30pt,210pt){\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \zorna{a}};  
 \node at (270pt,210pt){\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \zorna{b}};
 \draw[line width=2pt,double,color=MidnightBlue,
 fill=myblue!10,opacity=.5] (0,0) rectangle (300pt,240pt);
 \node[text width=240pt] at (150 pt,120 pt){%
  \begin{center}
      \color{MidnightBlue}
      \fontsize{24}{48}
      \selectfont tkz-base\\ 
 \end{center}};
\end{tikzpicture}}    
}
```

This block creates this:

[image]

Don't forget to update tkz-base and tkz-doc

Comment: @Thanks for the answer, are you sure about the name of the file `TKZdoc-base-main.tex` ? ...I'm using luatex in TeXLive 2020

Comment: Sorry it’s the name for the doc of tkz-base ! Here it’s TKZdoc-euclide-main.tex

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think something is wrong with the `couverture.tex` file when compiling with `lualatex` it doesn't find it and other errors appear with `xcolor` (`! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'myblue'`). I have placed a temporary note at the beginning.

Comment: I think TexLive is frozen. You need to take tkz-doc 1.3c on ctan. It might be the same for `tkz-euclide`, which is supposed to be version 3.05. The same goes for the documentation and `tkz-base`.

Comment: The correct version of both packages is installed, I am using TeXLive 2020 (pretest)

Comment: I like very much your answer. +1 surely.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Do you have couverture.tex in the `tkz-doc`? You need three packages `tkz-doc`, `tkz-base` and `tkz-euclide`. You can download and place them in the same folder.

Comment: See TMP EDIT for path, I have the impression that some route is not correct, when copying coverture I solve partially the problem, but, the file is already in the system...it is strange

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Sorry but I use TL2019 and what is TMP EDIT ?

Comment: Excuse my bad English :(, check the post above, I have placed the paths in which the files are installed in my system (fedora)

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL I'm not a big TeX specialist... There is `\input{couverture}`in `tkz-doc.cls`and `couverture.tex`is in the same folder. I just don't understand

Comment: But they are installed in different directories and kpse does not find `coverture`..`/doc/latex/tkz-doc/couverture.tex` and `/tex/latex/tkz-doc/tkz-doc.cls`

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Yes there is a problem because `couverture.tex`and `tkz-doc.cfg` must be in the same file as the other two. I never made a `doc` directory for this package. Sorry but it's not my fault. I'm going to do an update ! but tomorrow because I'm tired. It's been a tough day in Paris today.

Comment: Great, maybe you should leave a note for the TeXLive maintainers (I don't use MikTeX) so I don't know what's going on there... Can you include the instructions to generate the correct documentation for tkz-euclide in the future version?

Comment: Mon pays (Chile) est en passe d'aimer le vôtre :( ...covid-19 est arrivé partout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105662/discussion-between-alain-matthes-and-pablo-gonzalez-l).