# Checkboxes in front of labels

Tags: lists, boxes, enumitem

How do I create a checkbox in front of the label in an enumerate environment.  I don't want to change the label to a checkbox, but want a checkbox in front of the label.  So for example.

Answer the following questions by putting a check in the box if it applies to you.

Here is are some of the things I have tried.

I can made the label be a box, have a box around the number and I can put boxes at the end of the statement.
What I would like is for the box to come in front of the label instead of being around the label.
I would be happy with just the box, but the boxes with Yes and No would be even better.
I want the items in the list to be numbered so I can refer to them.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{checklist}{enumerate}{2}

\setlist[checklist]{label=$\square$}

\newcommand{\YesNo}{Yes $\square$ \quad No $\square$}

\begin{document}

Put a check in the box if the statement is mostly true about you. \\

\begin{enumerate}[label=\fbox{\arabic*}]
\item I can talk to strangers with relative ease. \
\end{enumerate}

\begin{checklist}
    \item I can talk to strangers with relative ease.
\end{checklist}

\begin{enumerate}
\item I can talk to strangers with relative ease. \YesNo 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Before piling up questions you should consider to accept answers to your old questions.

Comment: Since you seem to want to design a questionnaire, you may check out the `paperandpencil`package. It is mentioned in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118661/102176) to the question regarding packages to design questionnaires.

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure if this is meant, but the box is before the label:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{checklist}{enumerate}{2}

\setlist[checklist]{label={$\square$\quad\arabic*.}}

\newcommand{\YesNo}{Yes $\square$ \quad No $\square$}

\begin{document}

Put a check in the box if the statement is mostly true about you. \\

\begin{enumerate}[label=\fbox{\arabic*}]
\item I can talk to strangers with relative ease. \
\end{enumerate}

\begin{checklist}
    \item I can talk to strangers with relative ease.
\end{checklist}

\begin{enumerate}
\item I can talk to strangers with relative ease. \YesNo 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I go this proposal at another forum and it works great.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\checkbox}[1]{\protect\fbox{%
    \hbox to1em{\footnotesize\color{LightGray}\sffamily\hfil#1\hfil}}}
\begin{document}
Answer the following by marking the Yes or No box:
\begin{enumerate}

[label=\checkbox{Yes}\thinspace\checkbox{No}\thinspace\arabic*.,leftmargin=*]
\item I have read the documentation.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```